# Passing a javascript variable to a node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I am pretty new to Javascript and Node js but I have created a node script that scrapes data from a website.  The script scrapes the data and in my javascript page I call the function.  The data that I want all outputs onto screen fine but when I click on a hyberlink on the html page I want it to send the variable back to the node js and include it for another script.

This is my code for the Javascript file. I tried to store the value in a Cookie and then read it from the node js file but it kept coming up undefined.(Also for the in the code below i just stored the first variable in the array to the cookie)

```
function showJSONData()
{

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {       
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log(data);
        var output = '<table class=table>';                     
        for (var i = 0; i < data.arrivals.length; i++) {
            output += '<tr>';
            output += '<td>' + data.arrivals[i].id+ '</td>';
            output += '<td>' + data.arrivals[i].name+ '</td>';


            output +=  '<td> <a href="flight.html" ' + setCookie("value", data.arrivals[0].id) + '> View </a></td>';
```

In my node js script I would like to get the variable and include it in another function like so:

```
var cookies = req.cookies["value"];

app.get("/code", function(req,res){
    //var name = req.params.name;
    var url = 'https://data-live.tracker.com/clickhandler/?version=1.5&name=' + cookies;

    request(url, function(error, response, html){       
        var obj = JSON.parse(html);
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow! Where do you define your cookie ?

Comment: I define it in the Java script file   function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + ";path=/";
}

Comment: What about moving your line `var cookies = req.cookies...` inside the `app.get` callback function ?

Comment: No still saying undefined.  Is there any other way of passing the variable instead of using cookies? I have done research but cant seem to find anything